# how to control the for loop if the value is already detect?

Tags: django

\html

```
<select id="payments" name ="payments" onchange="payment(this.value)">
    <option value="0" name ="yearlvllist">-- Payment Type --</option>
   {% for paymentschedule in payment %}
    <option value="{{paymentschedule.Payment_Type.id}}" name ="payments">{{paymentschedule.Payment_Type}}</option>
    {% endfor%}
</select>
```

\views

```
def scheduleofpayment(request):
payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.all().filter(Education_Levels=paymentsid).order_by('Display_Sequence')
return render(request, 'accounts/scheduleofpayment.html', {"payment":payment})
```

\models

```
class ScheduleOfPayment(models.Model):
    Pending_Request = [
       ('Active', 'Active'),
       ('Inactive', 'Inactive'),
    ]
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    Payment_Type = models.ForeignKey(PaymentType, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    Date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    Amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    Remark = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True, null=True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, choices=Pending_Request,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        suser = '{0.Education_Levels}'
        return suser.format(self)
```

this is the image from my admin-site
[admin-site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkEGJ.png)

this is the result of what i filter in schedule of payment
[user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkEGJ.png)

My problem is how to control the looping of monthly in html template? without deleting the database. do you have an idea guys ?

Comment: What do you mean by control the looping? Is the goal only to show two options (Cash and  Monthly) in that dropdown?

Comment: yes, as you can see in dropdown, too many "monthly" right? i just want the result in dropdown is "cash" and "monthly"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is only to have `Cash` and `Monthly` under ***Payment Type*** then you can make use of the QuerySet's `distinct()` method.

*views.py*

```
  def scheduleofpayment(request):
      payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.all().filter(Education_Levels=paymentsid)
                .order_by('Display_Sequence').distinct('Payment_Type') 
return render(request, 'accounts/scheduleofpayment.html', {"payment":payment})
```

**OR**

Since you have a model for ***Payment Type*** can't you just use that to display your options?

*views.py*

```
def scheduleofpayment(request):
      payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.all().filter(Education_Levels=paymentsid)
                .order_by('Display_Sequence')
      payment_type = PaymentType.objects.all()

      context = {
          'payment': payment,
          'payment_type': payment_type,
      }

return render(request, 'accounts/scheduleofpayment.html', context)
```

*html*

```
\html
<select id="payments" name ="payments" onchange="payment(this.value)">
    <option value="0" name ="yearlvllist">-- Payment Type --</option>
    {% for type in payment_type %}
        <option value="{{type.id}}" name ="payments"> 
        {{ type.name }}</option>
    {% endfor%}
    {% endfor%}
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for the effort sir paolo but the distinct() method is not working, and I dont know why, btw about the models PaymentType , i have a particular reason why I didnt use it.

Comment: i use postgressql

Comment: payment = ScheduleOfPayment.objects.all().filter(Education_Levels=paymentsid).order_by('Payment_Type').distinct('Payment_Type') i did this sir Paolo , and i get what i desired answer, even your answer is incorrect you give me an idea to correct my problem, thank sir, i will mark your answer correct :)

Comment: Oh apologies, I missed the object name. Yes you are correct, it is ```.distinct('Payment_Type')```.